# Regex for date and replace its occurrence in string using stringByReplacingMatchesInString

Tags: ios, regex, date, nsstring

I need a regex for date like this, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss pm" and then I want to separate the string components using this regex match in some `NSString`.

For example if string is,

```
30/06/15 11:46:37 pm: Person1: Testing
30/06/15 11:46:40 pm: Person1: Hello...
30/06/15 11:46:52 pm: Person2: Hi 
30/06/15 11:47:06 pm: Person1: How are you doing
```

And the output components in array should be,

```
Person1: Testing
Person1: Hello...
Person2: Hi 
Person1: How are you doing
```

You can suggest any better idea to parse the string that contains chat text like above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This,
NSString *string = @"30/06/15 11:46:37 pm: Person1: Testing 30/06/15 11:46:40 pm: Person1: Hello... 30/06/15 11:46:52 pm: Person2: Hi 30/06/15 11:47:06 pm: Person1: How are you doing";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([0-9]{1,2})+\/+([0-9]{1,2})+\/+([0-9]{1,2})+ +([0-9]{1,2})+:+([0-9]{1,2})+:+([0-9]{1,2}) +(am|pm): " options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

Comment: can you tell me about the second part as how to separate string on basis of this?

Comment: "[ap]m" (or something like that), for "am" or "pm"? @iOSDeveloper You have to read about NSRegularExpression and how to find, and replace.

Comment: let me know wether every string ends with newline character or white space.

Comment: @johnykumar one more question, how can I automate the am,pm in date string I have used am|pm but it is only working for first part am.?

Comment: i will add that in regex let me know wether every string ends with newline character or white space.

Comment: the above code gives me null in log, i think the Template parameter need to be set

Comment: which template parameter?